# Split a PDF into single pages using PHP exec() and Python PDF stapler tool

Tags: php, python, permissions, pdf-generation, exec

A PHP based website I'm working on requires splitting PDF documents into single pages.
Having searched far and wide I have finally settled on using Stapler (https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler), a Python alternative to PDFtk.

**Note:** In my case the PDF files are placed in a directory above public access, alongside public_html. I have also placed stapler here.

---

The tool works beautifully when I run it through the console. Using the -v verbose option I results in the following output:

```
[root@server directory]# python2 stapler -v burst filename.pdf
Mode: burst
filename_1.pdf
filename_2.pdf

2 page(s) in 1 file(s) processed.
```

**SOLVED:** By using the -d option I was able to specify the output directory. Without any changes to the user apache runs under I am able to execute stapler from PHP.

```php
exec("python2 ../directory/stapler -vd ../directory burst ../directory/filename.pdf 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
```

Dump of $output:

```
Dump => array(5) {
  [0] => string(11) "Mode: burst"
  [1] => string(16) "filename_1.pdf"
  [2] => string(16) "filename_2.pdf"
  [3] => string(0) ""
  [4] => string(33) "2 page(s) in 1 file(s) processed."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that inside your php script the path you provide (filename.pdf) points to a valid file?

I would create an absolute path inside your script that passes `realpath`'s scrutiny and provide that as an argument inside your command.

Also, you can use `getcwd` to check what path is used when `exec` is called and see if it is the same that you are working with on the command line.

Comment: Hmm. `getcwd` got me thinking. I wrongly assumed stapler would look for filename.pdf in its own directory. By giving filename.pdf either a relative `../directory/filename.pdf` or absolute path `/srv/...`, the output is one extra line: `filename_1.pdf`, but halts right there again!

Comment: @David: `exec` has a third argument (passed by reference) that gives you the result of the function call, which is normally an integer that is 0 when the script ran successfully and some other number indicating an error. If it returns anything other than 0 there might be an error code you can google. Another thing you can try is adding `> /path/to/some/file` to see if there is any other output that is not captured, and `2> /path/to/some/other/file` to see if there is any error output.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on track. I had been printing an int(1) as the third parameter, but never thought to google it. Turns out `1` is the [catchall for general errors](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html). However, I did come across the usage of `2>&1` in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) which is supposedly for redirecting errors to the standard IO. More output now. See OP.

Comment: @David: Glad I could help. I don't know if this would work, but can you execute the command as sudo?

Comment: Stapler has the following option: `-d DESTDIR, directory where to store output file`. This solves my problem! Stapler was trying to output the files to the directory where exec() was being executed from. I should have figured this out after my first comment. Thanks for pitching in @DudeonRock!